# How do you read and quickly edit python code

Tags: python, dynamic-typing

I typically work with C++ but off late have to program a lot in Python. Coming from a C++ background, I am finding dynamic typing to be very inconvenient when I have to modify an existing codebase. I know I am missing something very basic and hence turning to the stackoverflow community to understand best practices.

Imagine, there is a class with a number of methods and I need to edit an existing method. Now, in C++, I could explicitly see the datatype of every parameter, check out the .h files of the corresponding class if need be and could quickly understand what's happening. In python on the other hand, all I see are some variable names. I am not sure if it is a list or a dictionary or maybe some custom datastructure with its getters and setters. To figure this out, I need to look at some existing usages of this function or run the code with breakpoints and see what kind of datastructure am I getting. I find either methods to be very time consuming. Is there a faster way to resolve this problem? How should I quickly determine what's the datatype of a particular variable?

The general impression is that code is easier to read/write in Python, but I am not finding it very quick to read python code because of lack of types. What am I missing here?

Comment: Read the unit tests for the method. They should illustrate the usage.

Comment: @LutzHorn Unfortunately a lot of scientific code (which is why I am using Python) doesn't come with unit tests. Currently, I look for usages elsewhere in the project and try to understand what's happening there - which is also non-trivial, because then I need to look at the entire call hierarchy of that particular function

Comment: that's the price to pay for the power of python. So dynamic no one can predict what's going to be set in params.

Comment: The code might be scientific but it is not well written if it lacks unit tests and API documentation. I fear you will have to either find the person who wrote the code and make him tell you the proper usage, or you will have to take the dusty road and step through the code.

Comment: Good Python code doesn't neglect documenting a function's parameters just because the language doesn't force you to.

Comment: When does knowing whether something is a dict or a list really tell you anything? If it's expecting a dict mapping user names to connection objects and you pass it a dict mapping file names to file objects, that's no better than passing it a list. You can tell that it wants a map of user names to connections by the function name, the parameter name, the docstring, the comments, the API docs, and the unit tests. Or, if you can't, you'd be just as screwed in C++ as in Python.

Comment: If you really want static type checking, you can run Mypy, and annotate whatever can't be inferred (or, if you can't/don't want to change existing code, write typesheds). Up-to-date IDEs will take advantage of this to statically type-check on the fly, and to show more information in their auto-complete and so on. It's still just going to tell you `Dict[str, file]`, but if you need that, you can have it.

Comment: One more thing: "some custom datastructure with its getters and setters" rarely exists in Python, and the same for a lot of the cruft that types are there to document in Java (and Java-like C++ designs). Also, types usually to follow standard protocols (even when not implementing an ABC) and idioms whenever reasonable. Unfortunately, this doesn't do you any good until you get a sense for what's "pythonic", but it doesn't take long to get that sense.

Comment: @abarnert Excellent comments. Mypy looks interesting, will check it out.    Dict and list was probably not the best example. Basically when there is no proper documentation in the code, ambiguous variable names such as  "images" are easier to resolve in C++ code for me - that could be because I have more C++ experience and don't think in the "pythonic" way as you mentioned. Like I mentioned, I thought python code is more "human readable", but that was not the case for me and hence this question.

Comment: Well, badly written Python code is still badly written… Also, in Python, you can get pretty far with a bare text editor, which means it's more of a jump when you do start needing go-to-def and fly-lint and things like that; in C++, you pretty much need a decent IDE or emacs or vim setup from day two, so there is no such hurdle. (There are python-mode commands I've been using once/week or so for a decade, so I still have to think each time, while the C++ equivalents are so ingrained in my fingers that my corpse will be typing them out if my coffin has a meta key.)

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain, too! I frequently switch between Python and C++, so paradigm shifting does give me paranoia.

However, I've been readjusting my codes with:

[Type Annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

It doesn't improve runtime performance, but it provides sense of comfort when reading through tens of thousands line of codes. Also, you can run your python programs with this to further verify your type annotations:

[mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/)

Answer (score 0):

These are the following things i follow:

1. Comment clearly what is being returned and what is the input in the `docstring`
2. Use a debug(or a Flag) variable, which is by default set to `False`, and keep a if block as follows.

   ```
   if debug:
       print(type(variable))
   ```

So, in that way, you would be sure to see what is the type of the variable.

Comment: Both is advice for the *author* of code, not for the *reader*.

Comment: I think , based on the question, author wants to read the code properly.

Comment: Well, yes. without changing code , how would he know what is the type of a object.

Comment: That is exactly his question

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can see the data type of any variable by using

```
type(variable_name)
```

It will show you data type of that variable. Such as int, bool, str, etc.